# React Native IOS app crashing when using navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated

I am using 
`react-native-reanimated`:`3.4.2` 
`react-native`:`0.72.3`

So when I am using navigation.reset or navigation.replace the iOS react native app is crashing without giving any information
but if you run your app using Xcode you will be able to see  `_clearAnimationConfigForTag`

it is crashing because of the reanimated latest library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So currently there is a bug in current 
`react-native-reanimated: 3.4.2` 
Here is the link of discussion: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/4836

The solution is to to download there official patch version for now until the bug is fixed in `3.5.0`
For now you can use this version `react-native-reanimated@nightly`

Note: Remove the `react-native-reanimated` library from your project

If you are using `yarn` 
`yarn add react-native-reanimated@nightly`

This will solve the crashing issue